# How do I change the formatting of standard types in C++ std::format?

Tags: c++, fmt

How can I customize the behaviour of std::format so I can get e.g. thousand separators for integer and float types?

Comment: try the locale specific formatting: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter

Comment: You can write wrapper template `MyFormattingWrapper<T>`  that simply contains `T` and specialize `std::formatter<MyFormatting<int>>` to be whatever you want. It won't change behavior for standart types but for when you wrap the type with `std::format(... MyFormattingWrapper(i))`

Comment: `std::format(std::locale("en_US"), "{:L}", 1000000)` gives me `1,000,000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [standard format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification) used for standard types, like integers and floating-point types, has an `L` option to enable locale-specific formatting:

> **L (locale-specific formatting)**
>
> The **L** option causes the locale-specific form to be used. This option is only valid for arithmetic types.
>
> - For integral types, the locale-specific form inserts the appropriate digit group separator characters according to the context's locale.
> - For floating-point types, the locale-specific form inserts the appropriate digit group and radix separator characters according to the context's locale.
> - For the textual representation of `bool`, the locale-specific form uses the appropriate string as if obtained with `std::numpunct::truename` or `std::numpunct::falsename`.

For example:

```
int intValue = 1000000;
double dblValue = 1000000.0;
std::format("{:L} {:L}", intValue, dblValue);
```

If the user's locale does not define a thousands separator, you can provide your own `std::locale` that does, eg:

```
#include <locale>

class MyNumPunct : public std::numpunct<char>
{
protected:
    char do_thousands_sep() const override { return ','; }
    std::string do_grouping() const override { return "\03"; }
};

...

std::format(
    std::locale( std::locale(""), new MyNumPunct ),
    "{:L} {:L}", intValue, dblValue
);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bKEGb3K4K)

Comment: I am a bit troubled by the `new MyNumPunct`. As I understand it this is a facet, but I cannot see in the documentation on cppreference that std::locale deletes this after use. However it seems it is the only way it works.

Comment: Oh. Found it. a facet is being deleted when it is no longer referenced.

Comment: @GenericName facets are reference counted. Per cppreference: [`std::locale::~locale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/%7Elocale): "*Non-virtual destructor which decrements reference counts of all facets held by `*this`. Those facets whose reference count becomes zero are deleted.*"

Comment: @GenericName also per cppreference: [`std::locale::facet`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/facet#Facet_class): "*Whenever a facet is added to a locale, the locale increments the reference count in the facet (through an implementation-specific mechanism). Whenever a locale is destructed or modified, it decrements the reference count in each facet it no longer implements. Whenever a facet's reference count becomes zero, the locale performs `delete static_cast<std::locale::facet*>(f);` where `f` is the pointer to the facet.*"